# Potential function for exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm dealing with this exercise.

"Given the general solution
\begin{equation} (1) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; y(x)=\pm \sqrt{K|x|-1} \;\;\;,\;\;  K>0\end{equation}
of an exact ODE. Find a potential function $\Psi (x,y)$ for the exact ODE that is solved by $(1)$.

So what does it actually mean? I have $y(x)$ so I can't really figure out why it ask for a potential function. I know an exact ODE is someting where you have
$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ but I can't figure out what I am supposed to do.

Comment: I would think it means to isolate $K$. Then the other side is a potential function in that solutions move along level curves.

Comment: Yea it's not a big deal to isolate $K$, but I still don't got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can assume $\,K\left|x\right|-1\,$ is non-negative, cause if it isn't your function $\,y(x)\,$ can't be a (real) solution.

Now,
$$\begin{align*}y=\pm\sqrt{K\left|x\right|-1}&\Longrightarrow \;y^2=K\left|x\right|-1\quad (1)\\
2yy'=K\frac{d}{dx}\left|x\right|=\pm\,K & \Longrightarrow\;2y\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\, K\end{align*}$$
$$\mp\,Kdx\,+\,2y\,dy=0 \quad(2)\\$$

You can define $\,M(x,y)=\mp\,K,\;N(x,y)=2y.$

Your potential function verifies: $\,\mathbf{F}=(M,N)=\nabla\Psi,\;$ so:
$$\Psi=\int\,M\,dx=\int\,N\,dy$$

Solving the equation $\,(2)\,$ for $\,\left|x\right|=x\,$ or $\,\left|x\right|=-x,\,$ you obtain two different potentials (apparently):

$$\begin{align*}\Psi(x,y)&=y^2-Kx\quad \textrm{if}\;x\geq0\\\
\Psi(x,y)&=y^2+Kx\quad\textrm{if}\;x<0\end{align*}$$

So, $\;y^2-K\left|x\right|=-1\;$ is your potential function, which can be obtained just isolating the variables in $\,(1).$

Comment: Wow I will read this carefully and try to figure it out.